# Xamarin.Forms refresh TextProperty of Editor

Tags: data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to change the text in an Editor cell after an event?

I have an Editor cell that shows an address from an SQLite database. I also have a button that gets the current address and shows this in an alert that asks if they would like to update the address to this. If Yes, then I would like to show the new address in the Editor cell.

```
public class UserInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string address;
    public string Address 
    { 
        get { return address; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(address, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                 return;
            }
            address = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

My code for the editor cell is

```
Editor userAddress = new Editor
{
    BindingContext = uInfo, // have also tried uInfo.Address here
    Text = uInfo.Address,
    Keyboard = Keyboard.Text,
```

};

and then this after it has got the current address I have this

```
bool response = await DisplayAlert("Current Address", "Would you like to use this as your address?\n" + currAddress, "No", "Yes");
   if (response)
   {
        //we will update the editor to show the current address
        uInfo.Address = currAddress;
   }
```

How do I get it to update the Editor cell to show the new address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the BindingContext of the control, but not specifying a binding to go with it.  You want to bind the TextProperty of the Editor to the Address property of your context.

```
Editor userAddress = new Editor
{
    BindingContext = uinfo,
    Keyboard = Keyboard.Text
};

// bind the TextProperty of the Editor to the Address property of your context
userAddress.SetBinding (Editor.TextProperty, "Address");
```

This may also work, but I'm not positive the syntax is correct:

```
Editor userAddress = new Editor
{
    BindingContext = uinfo,
    Text = new Binding("Address"),
    Keyboard = Keyboard.Text
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When I use userAddress.SetBinding (Editor.TextProperty, "Address"); I get a System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type

Comment: I'm pretty sure that syntax is correct.  If you look at the Xamarin ToDo sample there should be an editor control using that same binding approach.

Comment: Yep, it's the same as ToDo, but it throws the exception as the page is loading. I have just tried this - userAddress.SetBinding (Editor.TextProperty, new Binding("Address", BindingMode.TwoWay));, this still doesn't update the editor but it doesn't throw the exception either s- I guess that I am getting closer

Comment: I take that back, it does work - with this userAddress.SetBinding (Editor.TextProperty, new Binding("Address", BindingMode.TwoWay)); Thankyou Jason for leading me in the right direction